# Can CockroachDB save the results of a query to a CSV file?

Tags: cockroachdb

Is there a way to export the results of a running reporting query, or just to get the contents of a given table, to a CSV file (e.g. that could then be imported by Excel or similar)?

Answer (score 1):

You can export to CSV by running a `SELECT` statement from the command line with the `--format=csv` flag, e.g.:

`cockroach sql --format=csv -e 'SELECT * FROM bank.customers;' > csvtest.csv`